# Please provide assistance with complicated join across 7 related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of products (`Product`) with `ID` and `Name`. I have a linking table called `ProductCondition` with 3 fields (`ID, ProductID, ConditionID`). Each Product can have more than one `Condition`.

I need a query that will give me all products with the same `Condition` as a single `Product ID`.

To complicate matters, the same has to be performed with an `Ingredient` and an `End Use`, but these are or conditions.

I need all products that have the same condition or end use or ingredient as a single supplied `ProductID`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Image] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Condition](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Condition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductCondition](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ConditionID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductNotRecommended] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductCondition_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Product
ID Name
1  Product 1
2  Product 2
3  Product 3
4  Product 4
5  Product 5

Condition
ID Name
1  Condition 1
2  Condition 2
3  Condition 3
4  Condition 4
5  Condition 5

ProductCondition
ID  ProductID  ConditionID
1   1          1
2   1          2
3   2          1
4   3          3
5   4          2


Given a ProductID of 1, it has the following conditions:
1
2

So now I want to get all products that have a condition ID of 1 or 2
Product
ID  Name
1  Product 1
2  Product 2
3  Product 3
5  Product 5
```

This is only the 'Condition' case.  Exactly the same is required for 'End Use' and 'Ingredient'.

If I give an ID of a, and it has Conditions e and f, End Uses of h, j and m, and an Ingredient of p, I want all products that have a condition of e or f, or an End Use of h or j or m, or an ingredient of p.

Here's what I started with:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product p
--End Use
LEFT JOIN ProductEndUse pe ON p.ID = pe.ProductID
LEFT JOIN EndUse e ON e.ID = pe.EndUseID
-- Condition
LEFT JOIN ProductCondition pc ON p.ID = pc.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Condition c ON c.ID = pc.ConditionID
-- Ingredient
LEFT JOIN ProductIngredient pi ON p.ID = pi.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Ingredient i ON i.ID = pi.IngredientID

CROSS JOIN Product p2

-- [SOMETHING I don't know]

WHERE p2.ID = 1
```

Comment: Can you clarify. What does mean "as a single Product ID." Also, tag the post with server version.

Comment: I need to supplier just one Product ID to get a list of related product id's back

Comment: Can you provide the sample data and desired result.

Comment: Each product can have more than one condition. So what does "give me all products with the same Condition" mean? Don't answer my question with words. Instead, paste the CREATE TABLE statements, sample input, and sample output into your question.

Comment: Product 3 appears in your expected output, but it doesn't have a condition of either 1 or 2. Clarify what you expect.

Comment: I started this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e666/7). Maybe @Dave Robinson can add to it? Especially in terms of adding additional INSERT statements to show us more of your data? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the list of products that match on each of the categories, and union them together.

```
DECLARE @productid int;
set @productid = 1; --this is product to search for related items

SELECT p.ID as RelatedProductID, p.name as RelatedProductName, 'EndUse' as MatchType, e.name as MatchValue
FROM Product p
--End Use
INNER JOIN ProductEndUse pe ON p.ID = pe.ProductID
INNER JOIN EndUse e ON e.ID = pe.EndUseID
WHERE e.ID IN (select e2.EndUseID from product p2 inner join ProductEndUse e2 on p2.productid = e2.productid where p2.productid = @productid)

UNION

SELECT p.ID as productID, p.name as ProductName, 'Condition' as MatchType, c.name as MatchValue
FROM Product p
-- Condition
INNER JOIN ProductCondition pc ON p.ID = pc.ProductID
INNER JOIN Condition c ON c.ID = pc.ConditionID
WHERE c.ID IN (select pc2.ConditionID from product p2 inner join Condition pc2 on p2.productid = pc2.productid where p2.productid = @productid)

UNION

SELECT p.ID as productID, p.name as ProductName, 'Ingredient' as MatchType, i.name as MatchValue
FROM Product p
-- Ingredient
INNER JOIN ProductIngredient pi ON p.ID = pi.ProductID
INNER JOIN Ingredient i ON i.ID = pi.IngredientID
WHERE i.ID IN (select pi2.IngredientID from product p2 inner join Ingredient pi2 on p2.productid = pi2.productid where p2.productid = @productid)
```

If you only want the distinct list of product, and not show what was matched, then take off the `MatchType` and `MatchValue` columns from each section.

Comment: BateTech will be given the credits when my edit has been approved.  He was VERY close.